# RestSharp cannot send body content with get() method

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, httprequest, restsharp

I have using API from a courier company and I have to send body content in Get Method if I used POST Method it said it is not allowed and when use get it send me message you cannot sent body content in get method.
I am Using .Net Frame Work 4.8
Here is my code:

```
Dim client = New RestClient("https://smartlane.com.pk/api/production/consignment/track")
        'client.Timeout = -1
        Dim request = New RestRequest()
        request.Method = Method.Get
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "kA0HzgWQRaYRepL8ol8jmkHVJJIZRDQfx1zEqB")
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
        Dim body = "{" & vbLf & "    ""store_order_id"":[" & vbLf & "        ""1001"",""1002""" & vbLf & "    ]" & vbLf & "}"
        request.AddParameter("application/json", body, ParameterType.RequestBody)
        Dim response = client.Execute(request)
        Console.WriteLine(response.Content)
```

Comment: It is incredibly unusual (and really bad practice) to include a body when using GET, are you absolutely sure that is how the API is configured?

Comment: Yes here is documentation that i send you
<?php
/**
* Method: GET
*/$client = new Client();
$headers = [
'Authorization' => 'Bearer eUkPDTE9QXXX-YOUR-API-TOKEN-XXXKQhsujn1L',
'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
];
$body = [
"store_order_id" => [
"1001",
"1002",
]
];
$request = new Request('GET',
'https://v2.smartlane.dev/api/consignment/track',
$headers,
json_encode($body));
$res = $client->sendAsync($request)->wait();
echo $res->getBody();

Comment: Few things, 100% agree with first comment.  Would even go as far as say the error message is telling you exactly that.  Would also advise not posting authorization details on a public website and posting links to documentation (especially where people have to log in) isn't helpful.  Update you question with the relevant info.

Comment: In these sorts of situations, you're best to getting the request working in tools such as Postman, then replicate in code.

Comment: The issue is .NET version-specific. Normally, GET requests with body don't work in .NET Framework, and do work in .NET Core.

Answer (score 0):

As others already said, GET requests with body are very unusual. That said, you should be able to make this work on .NET Framework, if you use a different `HttpMessageHandler` than the default one. I am not familiar with VB.Net, but hopefully you’ll be able to use my C# example.

Reference [`System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler) nuget package, and initialize `RestClient` like this:

```cs
WinHttpHandler winHttpHandler = new WinHttpHandler();
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(winHttpHandler);
RestClientOptions restClientOptions = new RestClientOptions()
{
    BaseUrl = new Uri(@"https://smartlane.com.pk/api/production/consignment/track", UriKind.Absolute),
};
RestClient client = new RestClient(httpClient, restClientOptions);

RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
request.Method = Method.Get;
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "kA0HzgWQRaYRepL8ol8jmkHVJJIZRDQfx1zEqB");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
string body = "{ \"store_order_id\" : [ \"1001\", \"1002\" ] }";
request.AddParameter("application/json", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);
RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

There is also an overload of `RestClient` constructor that accepts `HttpMessageHandler`, which you probably could use to make the code more concise.